# Display loading spinner as a page loads

Tags: jquery, spinner, jquery-events

I would like to overlay a loading gif over my page contents as they load.  They are not loaded via ajax however and I have seen several solutions to display via that channel.  The issue is that a jQuery table is populated with search results and the table can take a decent time to render if a lot of results are returned via MySql.  I would like an overlay over the page to sort of hide the rendering of Javascript and jQuery.  Can someone explain how to accomplish this or point me to a great tutorial.  Remember, the page contents are not loaded from an external source (minus database values which are populated with PHP variables).

Comment: do you already have an event that triggers at load start?

Comment: i tried adding an onload event to the body tag but my function was either not called or was called and not seen.  I am unsure how to hide the spinnner after page load so they are currently in the same function.  This probably isnt corrent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wrapper div, add `display:none or opacity:0` and about the wrapper div put the spinny loader.

not in your jQuery add something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').show();
});
```

you can also add some animations as well instead of `show()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.loading
{
    background-image: url('loadingImage.png');
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width:100px;
    z-index:100;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append("<div class='loading' />").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: You can add the styles in loading class based on your requirement.

Comment: where is this wrapper div and can you show the styles applied to this div?

Comment: I applied to the main wrapper around all content and the styles were just the ones you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for the server to finish computing the page and you are using PHP then you can use the PHP function ob_flush() to flush the output buffer.

Provide the html code to show the loader then flush the buffer. Then run your database queries that take some time. You can flush the buffer as often as you'd like to possibly give status updates on the load progress as well.

Comment: I dont think its the query that is taking a long time, but rather the jQuery rendering the table with all the results.

Comment: Other posted solutions mention using an image within a CSS property to display the loader on the page. Assuming you have tried that and are not seeing the loader then the issue might be that jQuery rendering the table is overloading the browser, preventing the browser from rendering the CSS loader. Delay the jQuery table render for a brief second after showing the CSS loader.